# ¿Cómo puedo hacer una matriz en zig zag de esta forma?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Estoy practicando en C++ y tengo que hacer la impresión de una matriz que muestre los números del 1 al 9 de esta manera:
[image: La imagen presentada es el orden en el que se quieren colocar los datos]

Este es el codigo con el que intente hacer esta practica, pero no lograba soluciónar el problema a resolver por lo que agradeceria si me apoyaran con esta practica.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void Leer ( int X[][3]);
void Imprimir ( int X[][3]);

int main ( void )
{
    int X[3][3];

    Leer(X);
    Imprimir(X);

    return 0;
}

void Leer ( int X[][3])
{
    cout <<endl<< "\tBienvenido"<<endl<<endl;
    cout << "\tEste programa: "<<endl;
    cout << "\t1. Lee los datos asignados para la matriz."<<endl;
    cout << "\t2. Imprime los datos ingresados a la matriz."<<endl<<endl;
    cout <<"\tFavor de ingresar los datos de la matriz."<<endl;
  for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
  {
    for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
    {
        cout << "\tX[" << i << "][" << j << "]: ";
        cin >> X[i][j];
    }
  }
}

void Imprimir ( int X[][3])
{
    cout <<endl<< "\tLa matriz es: "<<endl;
  for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
  {
    for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
    {   
         cout <<"\t    " <<X[i][j]; 
    }
        cout<<endl; 
    }
  
}
```

Comment: El componente "y" lo que tiene que hacer es ir incrementando de uno en uno, el componente "x" primero irá en una dirección 0, 1, 2... y luego en dirección inversa: n, n-1, .... 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que se puede ver en ese *zig-zag* es que las filas pares se leen de izquierda a derecha mientras que las impares de derecha a izquierda, por lo tanto la función de lectura puede implementarse así:

```
void Leer(int (&matriz)[3][3])
{
    for (int indice = 0; indice != 9; ++indice)
    {
        const auto y = indice / 3;
        // Si es par: izquierda a derecha, si no derecha a izquierda
        const auto x = y % 2 ? 3 - 1 - (indice % 3) : indice % 3;

        std::cout << "\tmatriz[" << y << "][" << x << "]: ";
        std::cin >> matriz[y][x];
    }
}
```

Puedes generalizar el tamaño y el tipo de la matriz con plantillas:

```
template <typename T, auto F, auto C>
void Leer(T (&matriz)[F][C])
{
    for (int indice = 0; indice != F * C; ++indice)
    {
        const auto y = indice / C;
        const auto x = y % 2 ? C - 1 - (indice % C) : indice % C;

        std::cout << "\tmatriz[" << y << "][" << x << "]: ";
        std::cin >> matriz[y][x];
    }
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVFNT4NAED33/YqxRgvWxo8YD9DWA0kTE4/ekMO6bOsqLLgsFTT96@JS8Dsx8bDZeTPvZWbe8DyfrDhvml2peFLGgqYyK4wWLJ0DRqR5woxNmjoXiqWCrg@JlSajRf8Hc6wzGdOVENq5Jmc/ZUbLZzdcRGEQuXjBYJlpcqQyJFUsuaAZHfvv8c6MFnRAgU/jcZdyMbCaAc9UYboWtVX09CPL/F6sbLGmPTqlCwpoQif2OT17jwKXPPpEPqy4MLHn8aw0NJ3S8MZ0A4fDFtbbXNSBqgMeDf0PmVQ0n1MvqaOwimxtg82/vLpMcy1T@adfX1bcX8qEeX3T3p5fnDVLbMqjlms5P9bsqjYY0cj/6cHoRo3et2jPlDKpnO0k/I5pqsLzKDyLXjate9szV66lfyzRIgy0MKVW9rLYNA3DLThiCCyxwh0k7vGABCkUMuR4hEYBgxJrPKHCK18mbFU0EzvXjI/Hp@wN)</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

El truco es que las "y" siempre aumentan si te fijas. Las "x" deben alternar entre ir hacia adelante: 0, 1, 2, ... e ir hacia atrás n, n-1, ... 2, 1, 0.

Eso lo puedes conseguir simplemente con una variable booleana.

```
bool x_van_hacia_adelante = true; 
for( int y = 0; y < 2; y++ ) {
    if( x_van_hacia_adelante ) {
       // aquí hay que hacer un contador donde las 
       // x se muevan en dirección 0, 1, 2, 3...
    } else {
       // aquí hay que hacer un contador donde las
       // x vayan al revés ... 3, 2, 1, 0 
    }
    // alternamos el valor de x_van_hacia_adelante:
    // cuando es true, pasará a valer falso, cuando
    // es falso, pasará a valer cierto
    x_van_hacia_adelante = !x_van_hacia_adelante; 
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la aclaración, afortunadamente ya salio la practica @Raul Luna

Comment: @PanchoFernandez ¿qué significa *afortunadamente ya salió la práctica*? Si has hallado una solución distinta a la planteada, eres bienvenido a publicarla como respuesta a tu propia pregunta. En cambio si la solución aportada aquí es similar a la tuya, lo idóneo es aceptar la respuesta como válida y votar positivo. Es lo que ayuda a crecer a la comunidad. Saludos